# Switch between normal and split-screen (vr mode)

Tags: screen, google-cardboard

I have a virtual reality (VR) headset:

**How can I change the mode of the phone so that I can use the phone and all the normal phone apps while wearing the VR headset?**

In other words I need to switch the phone display between splil-screen (oculus mode) and normal mode. In other words, like for 3D, the display should be split into 2 smaller screens (but identical).

***Related info for those who are interested:***

It seems that there are a few apps available for watching normal videos in VR mode:

- Any Youtube video on your device can be switched to VR mode.
- Convert normal videos to VR mode by using HMD-Video-Converter.
- Play normal videos on the VR headset using:

  - [VR Cinema for Cardboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.mobius.vrcinema&hl=en)
  - [CINEVEO - VR Cinema](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mindprobe.cineveovr&hl=en)
  - [Side-By-Side Video Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.funghisoft.sbsvideoplayer&hl=en)
  - [MO3D for Cardboard VR Cinema](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pps.mo3d&hl=en) (paid)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible yet, but google is working on [DayDream](https://vr.google.com/daydream/) which is gonna do the thing you want soon 
If you want to play your normal videos in VR mode, thats possible using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abg.VRVideoPlayer&hl=en). (There are quite a lot other apps doing the same thing, but i personally use the one I gave link to)

Heres one more [link](http://techapple.net/2016/02/top-5-free-vr-video-player-apps-android-360-sbs-3d/) for 5 Top Videos players to run 360 Videos
 
Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the info, Siddhesh. And it seems that the VaR's VR Video Player you suggested got better ratings.